# How to use a $ sign in minted?

Tags: minted

I have code like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[ht]
    \begin{minted}{csharp}
    private static string Abc() =>
                \$"Abc";
    \end{minted}
\caption{Abc}
\label{listing:Abc}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

and i have frame like this (compiled on overleaf):

[image]

With Only "$":

[image]

How can I get rid of the red frame?

Comment: Can you please post a complete compilable example?  It is easier to help if you post something that can be compiled without having to guess your environment.

Comment: Just speculating: looks, like environment minted might not require backslashing ... so what  happens if you delete the backslash?

Comment: @MS-SPO is the same. I embedded new image in post.

Comment: @Thruston of course. Embedded in post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to escape the `$`.

This is a `pygments` bug relating to its C# lexer, see https://github.com/pygments/pygments/issues/1573, which has been fixed in `pygments` 2.10.0, released on August 15th, 2021.

**Jun 12, 2022 updates:**

Unfortunately, Overleaf.com's texlive 2021 still provides `pygments` v2.9.0. You can check by compiling the example below on overleaf:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\begin{document}
\bash[stdout]
pygmentize -V
\END
\end{document}
```

**How I find the above info**

- The red frame in pdf output is the style of `pygments` parsing error, indicating it's a `pygments` issue.
- Then I tested OP's minted snippet both locally and on https://pygments.org/demo/#try, and each of them works ok (with non-escaped `$`). I also checked `$"string"` is a [valid C# syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31014895). All that suggest it's a fixed `pygments` issue.
- So I directly jump to [`pygments`' changelog](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/blob/master/CHANGES) and search for "c#/csharp". This gives

  > - Updated lexers:
  >
  >   - [...]
  >   - C# (#1573, #1869)
- I checked [`#1573`](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/issues/1573) and found it's exactly the same issue OP encountered.
- The rest is straight: checking that issue was fixed and the fixing was published, getting the minimal version containing the fixing (double checked with the sectioning lines in `CHANGE`).

Comment: How can I use this new version?

Comment: If I try `pip install pygments` I get that the last version is 2.9.0. On the other hand, the Pygments site says that the last version is 2.10.0. Isn't it weird?

Comment: @M.Jaskuski @egreg I successfully have 2.10.0 installed from `pip`. Try `pip install pygments --upgrade` instead or perhaps you should check your [`pip` trusted host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60815199).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Is It possible to use this on overleaf?

Comment: Unfortunately no. overleaf still provides `pygments` v2.3.1, kind of outdated. You can see the version by compiling `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\begin{document}
\bash[stdout]
pygmentize -V
\END
\end{document}`